# Submit form to PHP with button name after disabling the button on form submit JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form which uses php for form processing. I don't the user to submit the form twice. I've tried to use jquery to disable the form on submit. but the problem is it disables the button but don't submit the form to php.

I want to detect the form submission with the submit button name.

```js
$('form').submit(function(){
    $(this).find('button[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="signup.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal m-t-30" novalidate>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-12">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Choose a Username" maxlength="15" id="username" class="form-control" required>
            <div class="form-errors <?php echo isset($errors['username']) ? 'filled' : ''; ?>"><?php echo $errors['username'] ?? ''; ?></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-12">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your Email address" id="email" class="form-control" required>
            <div class="form-errors <?php echo isset($errors['email']) ? 'filled' : ''; ?>"><?php echo $errors['email'] ?? ''; ?></div>
        </div>
    </div>                            

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-12">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password" id="password" class="form-control" required>
            <div class="form-errors <?php echo isset($errors['password']) ? 'filled' : ''; ?>"><?php echo $errors['password'] ?? ''; ?></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-12">
            <p class="font-12">By registering you agree to the Pawnhost Terms of Use</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group text-center m-t-20">
        <div class="col-12">
            <button type="submit" name="signup-submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary w-md waves-effect waves-light">
                <span id="btnLoading" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></span>
                <span id="btnText">Create My Account</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row m-b-0 mt-4">
        <div class="col-12 text-center">
            <a href="login.php" class="text-muted">Already have an account? Login</a>
        </div>                              
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the attribute, not the property.

```
$('form').on('submit', function(event){ $(this).find('button[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); });
```

OP also wanted to include the button in the form submission. This can be achieve by instead of using a button, using an input tag.

```
<input type="submit" name="mybtn" value="myval" />
```

Comment: Still, it doesn't submit the form

Comment: I want to detect the form submission with the button name

Comment: @lachiweb I've altered my answer. You can also check the event to see which button triggered the submit.

Comment: Nope, in the post superglobal, I can only see the username, email, and password not the button name.

Comment: @lachiweb that wasnt your initial question. You can add a name attribute to your button to add it to form submission.

Comment: Strange. In my local test cases I always get the clicked buttons value if it contains a name. You are checking the $_POST variable directly? Maybe you need to add a value too?

Comment: Yes, I'm using `print_r($_POST);` and the value don't works

Comment: Maybe try using <input type="submit" name="mybtn" value="myval" /> ?

Comment: But wait on changing `button[type=submit]` to `input[type=submit]` it stopped working.

Comment: What stopped working? The form submission or setting the disabled attribute?

Comment: form submission. the submit input name stopped showing in the post superglobal.

Comment: So it worked before but not anymore? Maybe the name exists somewhere else on the form or the value isn't set?

Comment: It worked before because we were disabling the button not the input we just changed to.

Comment: Well in our case we could add a CSS class that has "pointer-events: none" or maybe even hide the button completely

Comment: Okay, I'll try that. anyway, thanks for your time. I'll figure out something.

Comment: Yeah I&#39;ve ran into obstacles like these as well before. I think I fixed it back then by wrapping labels around buttons with radio buttons in them with different values so the radio would be checked when the button was clicked.